# ansible find path not works with jinja IF conditions

Tags: ansible

I have below script. Goal is to set  pattern variable `my_pattern` in FIND  based on condition ( OS ).
I used jinja condition, but not works as expected.
Even in Debug Pattern2 show correct string : in final FIND command no results found.
For testing When I set this my_pattern via standard  set_fact  with no jinga condition, then it works ( Debug path2 ).
Target file is just example.

```
---
- hosts: all


  tasks:


  - name: set  file pattern
    set_fact:
      my_pattern: "{% if ansible_distribution == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '6'  %}
      redhat-rel*
      {% else %}
      resolv.co*
      {% endif %}"


  - name: Debug Pattern
    debug:
      msg: "OS: {{ansible_distribution}} ver {{ansible_distribution_major_version}} pattern {{my_pattern}}"

  - name: Debug Pattern2
    debug:
      msg: "{{my_pattern}}"


  - name: Find installation package
    find: paths="/etc/" patterns="{{ my_pattern }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: file_path


  - name: Debug path
    debug:
      msg: "{{ file_path.files[0].path  }}"
    ignore_errors: true


  - name: set pattern by static  this works
    set_fact:
      my_pattern: resolv.co*

  - name: Find installation package by static  This works
    find: paths="/etc/" patterns="{{ my_pattern }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: file_path2

  - name: Debug path2
    debug:
      msg: "{{ file_path2.files[0].path }}"
```

Output:

```
PLAY [all] ***************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01]

TASK [set  file pattern] *************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01]

TASK [Debug Pattern] *****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01] => {
    "msg": "OS: RedHat ver 7 pattern  resolv.co* "
}

TASK [Debug Pattern2] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01] => {
    "msg": " resolv.co* "
}

TASK [Find installation package] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01 -> localhost]

TASK [Debug path] ********************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 0\n\nThe error appears to be in '/opt/mie_ansible_control/playbooks/carbon_deploy/test.yml': line 33, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Debug path\n    ^ here\n"}
...ignoring

TASK [set pattern by static  this works] *********************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01]

TASK [Find installation package by static  This works] *******************************************************************************************
ok: [host01 -> localhost]

TASK [Debug path2] *******************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host01] => {
    "msg": "/etc/resolv.conf"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you issue is your variable is padded with whitespace before and after it which will result in your find path not evaluating correctly and not finding anything. You can correct this using [Whitespace Control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#whitespace-control). Or you could just use a ternary if condition

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: set  file pattern
      set_fact:
        my_pattern: "{% if ansible_distribution == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '6' -%}
      redhat-rel*
      {%- else -%}
      resolv.co*
      {%- endif %}"
        my_ternary_pattern: "{{ 'redhat-rel*' if ansible_distribution == 'RedHat' and ansible_distribution_major_version == '6' else 'resolv.co*' }}"

    - name: Debug Pattern
      debug:
        msg: "OS: {{ansible_distribution}} ver {{ansible_distribution_major_version}} pattern {{my_pattern}}"

    - name: Debug Pattern2
      debug:
        msg: "{{my_pattern}}"

    - name: Debug Pattern2
      debug:
        msg: "{{my_ternary_pattern}}"
```

**OUTPUT**
Now the text is no longer padded

```
ansible@87330b5e9a07:/local$ ansible-playbook test.yml 
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 09 April 2023  13:58:49 +0100 (0:00:00.014)       0:00:00.014 **********
ok: [localhost]

TASK [set  file pattern] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 09 April 2023  13:58:50 +0100 (0:00:00.756)       0:00:00.771 **********
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Debug Pattern] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 09 April 2023  13:58:50 +0100 (0:00:00.019)       0:00:00.790 **********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "OS: Debian ver 10 pattern resolv.co*"
}

TASK [Debug Pattern2] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 09 April 2023  13:58:50 +0100 (0:00:00.019)       0:00:00.809 **********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "resolv.co*"
}

TASK [Debug Pattern2] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Sunday 09 April 2023  13:58:50 +0100 (0:00:00.017)       0:00:00.827 **********
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "resolv.co*"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Sunday 09 April 2023  13:58:50 +0100 (0:00:00.028)       0:00:00.855 **********
===============================================================================
gather_facts ------------------------------------------------------------ 0.76s
debug ------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.07s
set_fact ---------------------------------------------------------------- 0.02s
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
total ------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.84s
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the logic into the *group_vars/all*. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/my_pattern.yml
my_pattern_dict:
  RedHat:
    '5': redhat-rel*
    '6': redhat-rel*
    '7': redhat-rel*
  CentOS:
    '5': centos-rel*
    '6': centos-rel*
    '7': centos-rel*
    '8': centos-rel*
  Ubuntu:
    '18': lsb-rel*
    '20': lsb-rel*
    '22': lsb-rel*
  FreeBSD:
    '12': os-rel*
    '13': os-rel*
    '14': os-rel*

my_pattern: "{{ my_pattern_dict[ansible_distribution]
                               [ansible_distribution_major_version] }}"
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: distribution
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ ansible_distribution }}
          {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}
          {{ my_pattern }}

    - ansible.builtin.find:
        file_type: any
        paths: /etc
        patterns: "{{ my_pattern }}"
      register: file_path
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ file_path.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l test_24,test_11,localhost

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Ubuntu 20 lsb-rel*
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: FreeBSD 13 os-rel*
ok: [test_24] => 
  msg: CentOS 8 centos-rel*

TASK [ansible.builtin.find] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
ok: [test_24]
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - /etc/lsb-release
ok: [test_24] => 
  msg:
  - /etc/centos-release
  - /etc/centos-release-upstream
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg:
  - /etc/os-release
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, yes, this is another option.
I was just interesting how to do it via jinja IF/ELSE.